# SoundCloud JS SDK - SC.get is not working at all on IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, sdk, soundcloud

I'm trying to fetch information about a track like so:

```
SC.get('/tracks/15158492', {limit: 1}, function(track) { console.log(track); });
```

Which works great on all real web browsers, but Internet Explorer just won't budge. I'm suspecting that the problem has something to do with the ajax call, which according to the Network tab in IE dev-tools there isn't any (if you believe anything it says).

I've found only one related post, which is kind of old (and unresolved), on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/soundcloudapi/GuiKpbxHIWU

Also, I am aware that I can access the API directly using my own ajax request, but I am looking for a way simpler solution or at least an understanding as to why won't the SDK work and is it just me or is it a bug that needs to be fixed by SoundCloud.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake who caused this issue. I had a different issue some time ago in which sometimes on IE a div (`#recorderFlashContainer`) would appear in the middle of the screen for no reason. I understand that this is part of the communications done under IE extreme conditions, but it's a problematic UI bug. To fix it I added a CSS rule declaring `display: none` on the element, thus causing IE not to load the `object` element inside, which caused some on the SDK's functionality to fail.

I fixed it using another CSS rule, declaring:

```
/* SoundCloud Fix for IE9 */
#recorderFlashContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px!important;
    left: -9999px!important;
}
```

So thanks a lot for the help which made me realize that it's something I'm doing who's causing this issue.

On the same matter, why does the original bug happen? Why is it that sometimes (but not all the time) `#recorderFlashContainer` would get stuck in the middle of the screen? Is there something that can be done on your side to prevent it from happening?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this with simple test. Is there anything specific that you think caused that div to appear?

Comment: It has happened before in another part of our site, almost a year ago (was solved using the same trick, display: none) and I still haven't been able to reproduce it on demand, so I have no idea what may have caused it :\ All I can say is that this bug is very old.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have compatibility mode on?

The following code works for me in IE9 on Windows 7

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    redirect_uri: "http://example.com/callback.html",
  });
  SC.get("/groups/55517/tracks", {limit: 1}, function(tracks){
    alert("Latest track: " + tracks[0].title);
  });
</script>
```

Here's an example code – http://jsbin.com/erokoz/3/edit

Comment: I've found the source of the problem. If you can explain the situation more I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Explain what? Do you mean the compatibility mode? When IE is in compatibility mode, it behaves as IE of older version, meaning that JS engine and CSS engines are supporting far less features and have more bugs. That's the reason why SDK might not work properly in compatibility mode. Google “IE compatibility mode” to understand what might trigger it.

Comment: I was referring to my answer  from an hour ago. Why `#recorderFlashContainer` is sometimes showing in the middle of the screen? There was no "compatibility mode" to being with.